# Is starting an interval from within a timeout an issue

Tags: javascript

In an iframe on my website I want to run a polling function. I want it to run 800ms after the page loads and then every 100ms after that.

I'm currently doing this but want to know if it can cause any problems:

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){
            foo();
            window.setInterval(function(){
                foo();
            }, 100)
        }, 800);
```

Comment: why would that cause a problem

Comment: I don't know. I'm coming from C# and a lot of what I do in JS just feels... dirty.

Comment: it wont cause a problem, unless there is a huge task inside the interval and you calling it on each 100ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `setTimeout` does is execute the function contained within after the specified delay. It will not have any impact on your `setInterval` call. The only difference between having the `setInterval` inside the `setTimeout` is that it will only be triggered after the 800ms delay has elapsed.

If your `foo` function is designed to always repeat itself, you could place a second `setTimeout` into that function instead:

```
function foo() {
    window.setTimeout(foo, 100);
}
```

Now all you'd need to do is call `foo()` the once within your `setTimeout`:

```
window.setTimeout(foo, 800);
```

This is pretty much entirely down to personal preference though. Obviously this approach would not be ideal if your `foo` function is designed to be called elsewhere as well.

---

#### Demo

```js
var count = 0,
    elem = document.querySelector('p');

function foo() {
  elem.innerHTML = ++count;
  window.setTimeout(foo, 100);
}

window.setTimeout(foo, 800);
```

```html
<p>Count will be displayed here after the 800ms timeout finishes...</p>
```